# What needs to be configured so that the texts don't wrap?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools, mobile-browser

I'm building a website using WordPress. Although the pages are well suited for Mobile site, this particular page is displayed very congested. This is the page from the website website - http://www.cyberfosters.com/anspress/

If you click F12 using Chrome browser on this page and toggle the "Device Mode" you'll see how it appears on a mobile device, I'm going through the CSS files to find out what needs to be changed but I can't seem to find out.
What I want is that the page should appear on a mobile as it does on the website but just scaled down.

Comment: Dead link, and not enough information in the question to keep it open. Voting to close - please always provide enough information in the question itself, so that a link is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at your html and css and the problem seems to be very simple, your site is not build to small deviced because it uses a mix of width values in PX and %, the design must be set in % to work well on multiple devices without using special pages for mobiles and other for pc this is my recomendation.

Example if you put a 1090px image on a 800px screen resolution it will just not work so what we do is to set image width value to 100% in this case and so on that way the images get auto resized the easy way. Do the same with tables images divs spans etc

Comment: That means all I have to do is set the values from em/px to % ?
That will fix it?

Comment: I am looking at your site from a Xperia right now and almost everything seems fine the only problem width the width is in the top menu, this must the fixed look     .ubermenu .ubermenu-submenu.ubermenu-submenu-id-375 { width:300px; min-width:300px; }

Comment: Are you sure you're looking it as a mobile site and not as a desktop site? Because it's messed up on my MotoG

Comment: Looking from my xperia M and from a samsung S5 almost working fine just the menu looks bad. Change the width of the menu take the 300px off and seriously rewrite the design you have the same css and js files repeated over and over and the CDATA visible does not look so good you have more than 20 css files and 20 js files for something so small